# Mailchimp extension limits to most recent 25 lists

Tags: extension

We have a Civi user connected to Mailchimp who has quite a few lists - from our testing (Mailchimp v 1.6, Civi v 4.4.6) the extension appears only to access the 25 most recent lists in Mailchimp.  How can this limitation be increased?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I'd do is upgrade the extension from 1.6 to 1.8 to see if this issue has already been addressed. If it still remains, then I would create an issue at https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/issues

Comment: It does not appear to make a difference on this issue, and we have indeed reached out to the developers.

Answer (score 2):

Any use of the api without specifying the options.limit return only 25 results. So my guess is the MailChimp extension doesn't specify this option when retrieving the list of groups.

But as mentionned by Joe Murray, it's seems to be a bug in the extension that need to be fixed and an issue has been logged - https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/issues/155

So there not much we can do here.

Answer (score 2):

Follow up:  This limitation has been removed and should be available in the next extension upgrade.  See: https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/pull/158/files